# MemoryMappedFile.openExisting : specified file not found when using 2 different process

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

I am using 2 different processes, Say -

**Process1.exe** : perform some operation and updates a string variable which will be saved in a **MemoryMappedFile**(To acheive IPC) which is **file**

**Process2.exe**: Calls **Process1**. After completion of "Process1", it tries to open MemoryMappedFile **file** and gets the string for further use.

here are the code snippets -

**Process1.exe**

```
//Some code
public void DoSomeStuff()
{
onst int MMF_MAX_SIZE = 4096;
const int MMF_VIEW_SIZE = 4096;
try
   {
     using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("file", MMF_MAX_SIZE, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite))
     {
          using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream(0, MMF_VIEW_SIZE))
          {
               Message message1;
               message1.strName = "Some name";
               BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
               formatter.Serialize(stream, message1);
          }
     }
   }
catch(Exception e)
{
     MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
}
```

**Process2.exe**

```
        const int MMF_VIEW_SIZE = 4096;

        using (MemoryMappedFile file = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("file"))
        {
            using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = file.CreateViewStream(0, MMF_VIEW_SIZE))
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[MMF_VIEW_SIZE];
                Message message1;
                if (stream.CanRead)
                {
                    stream.Read(buffer, 0, MMF_VIEW_SIZE);
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
                    {
                        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        message1 = (Message)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
                        string name = message1.strName;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is my Message class which is written inside both the processes,

```
class Message
{
    public string strName;
}
```

**Issue:** after completion of **Process1** it has successfully written the string data to **MemoryMappedFile** but when I am trying to open **file** in **Process2** using line

> **MemoryMappedFile file = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("file")**

I am getting error - `Specified file not found`.

I am very new with **MemoryMappedFile** implementation to acheive IPC. Can someone suggest what's wrong I'm doing here?

Comment: In `OpenExisting`, "existing" is "I know that someone else currently has this open as a memory mapped file". Since your effectively running one program and letting it exit before the second program takes over, you don't need IPC. Why not use a plain file?

Comment: The odds that both processes will be able to find "file" are minuscule.  Always use full path names, c:\foo\bar\baz.ext.  A file like this needs to be writable so you'll favor creating it in an AppData directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267561(v=vs.110).aspx) you used will create a non-persisting memory mapped file. At the end of the using (`MemoryMappedFile mmf =`) (or at the end of `Process1`) the file will be "destroyed" (it will cease to exist).

Solution: use a real file.

Other solution could be to open the memory map in the parent process before calling the child process. There is even a [`CreateOrOpen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn765234(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that accepts a `HandleInheritability` to pass the handle to the child process (I don't know exactly how), but perhaps it isn't necessary.

Comment: It perfectly does the work when you create the MemoryMappedFile in parent(Process1) before starting the child(Process2). Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

If you want your In-Memory MMF to be accessed across the process add `"Global\\"` prefix to its name. Also, make sure to prevent the MMF from getting disposed of by adding it to a collection. You can try something similar as below:

```
var mmFName = $"Global\\{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}";
var mmf = System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(
                    mmFName,
                    allocationSize,
                    MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite,
                    MemoryMappedFileOptions.None,
                    securityDescriptor,
                    HandleInheritability.Inheritable);
```